# Big Problems with Blender exported FBX File for Unreal Engine

Tags: rendering, export, .fbx, unreal-engine

I have a really annoying problem with Blender....

First of all, I'm a real bloody beginner in Blender and don't have a clue. My problem isn't shown anywhere or I can't find anything about it.

To the problem. I got a .blend file on Sketchfab. This is a gaming PC. As soon as I render this model, it is displayed correctly, but as soon as it is exported as an FBX file... everything seems to be missing. Only the rough models are available and the materials etc are not displayed.

What am I doing wrong... Blender is the newest Version.

[image: render_result][Rendered IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jy4Z.png)

[image: PC]

[image: Render-Settings]

Comment: First Image is the Export Result
Second is the Object
last are the settings

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures